Prerender or SSG for a leaflet react page
Is there a method to prerender a page which is mainly a huge leaflet.js window ?
The window is always starting out at the same coordinates so It would be beneficial to prepare the initial view at build time so as to optimize load times of the page.
But I've tried a few SSG tools/frameworks at this point and they all fail, usually due to calls to the window api.
Tried next, vite/vike, snap.
The component looks more or less like this:
import L from "leaflet";
import {
...
} from "react-leaflet";

    <MapContainer
        crs={crs}
        center={startPosition}
        zoom={2}
        scrollWheelZoom={true}
        minZoom={2}
        maxZoom={13}
        zoomControl={false}
        style={{ width: "100%", height: "calc(70vh)" }}
        /* eslint-disable-next-line tailwindcss/no-custom-classname */
      >
        <ZoomControl position="bottomright" />
        <ScaleControl position="bottomleft" />
        <LayersControl position="topright">
          <LayersControl.BaseLayer name="Ortofoto">
            <TileLayer
              minZoom={2}
              maxZoom={13}
              attribution={myAttributionText}
              crossOrigin={true}
              url={`https://services.datafordeler.dk/GeoDanmarkOrto/orto_foraar_wmts/1.0.0/WMTS?username=${datafordelerUsername}&password=${datafordelerPassword}&service=WMTS&request=GetTile&version=1.0.0&Layer=orto_foraar_wmts&style=default&format=image/jpg&TileMatrixSet=KortforsyningTilingDK&TileMatrix={z}&TileRow={y}&TileCol={x}`}
            />
          </LayersControl.BaseLayer />
          <LayersControl.Overlay name="Skoledistrikter">
          <GeoJSON data={districtsJson} />
          </LayersControl.Overlay>
        </LayersControl>
        <MarkerClusterGroup
    
        </MarkerClusterGroup>
      </MapContainer>


I've fixed this in a Vue app by placing the import inside the onMounted function. Then it's only executed at runtime.
I don't have react experience, if they have a similar lifecycle hook you can move it there.
onMounted(async () => {
  const Leaflet = await import('leaflet')
})


that makes it not prerender the map at all. It's missing the point of optimizing the map load time
